# SpringData MongoDB Repositories Query on multiple fields in nested object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having trouble with a query on a nested object with two parameters.

Here is my document :

```
@Document(collection = "contracts")
public class Contract {
    @Id
    String _id;
    List<Stakeholder> stakeholders;
    Long contractRef;
}
```

Here is my nested object :

```
public class Stakeholder{
    String nationalId;
    String stakeholderRole;
}
```

I'm using mongoRepository to query this collection :

```
public interface ContractRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contract, String> {
@Query( value = "{'countryBranchCode' : ?0, 'contractRef' : ?1, 'stakeholders' : {'nationalId' : ?2, 'stakeholderRole' : ?3} }",
        fields = "{'stakeholders.$.':1}")
Contract findStakeholderByContractRefAndNationalIdAndStakeholderRole
        (String countryBranchCode, Long contractRef, String nationalId, String stakeholderRole);
```

Basically, I want to find a contract with contractRef and a stakeholder with both nationalId and stakeholderRole matching.

I tried a simplier query :

```
@Query( value = "{'countryBranchCode' : ?0, 'contractRef' : ?1, 'stakeholders.nationalId' : ?2, 'stakeholders.stakeholderRole' : ?3  }",
        fields = "{'stakeholders.$.':1}")
Contract findStakeholderByContractRefAndNationalIdAndStakeholderRole
        (String countryBranchCode, Long contractRef, String nationalId, String stakeholderRole);
```

But this can return a contract which has a stakeholder with the matching nationalId and wrong role, and another stakeholder with the wrong nationalId and good role for example, so that's not what I want.

Comment: Try `@Query( value = "{'countryBranchCode' : ?0, 'contractRef' : ?1, 'stakeholders' : { 'stakeholderRole' : ?2, 'nationalId' : ?3} }",
        fields = "{'stakeholders.$.':1}") Contract findStakeholderByContractRefAndStakeholderRoleAndNationalId
        (String countryBranchCode, Long contractRef,String stakeholderRole,  String nationalId);` Order is important for equality matches when matching whole embedded document.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think the order was important. I edited the Stakeholder object to match what I really have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
@Query( value = "{'countryBranchCode' : ?0,'contractRef':?1,'stakeholders':{'$elemMatch':{'nationalId':?2,'stakeholderRole':?3}}}",
fields = "{'stakeholders.$.':1}")
Contract findStakeholderByContractRefAndStakeholderRoleAndNationalId (String countryBranchCode, Long contractRef,String stakeholderRole, String nationalId);
```

Comment: It works! I didn't know about this operator, thank you